# Server Monitor with Console

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm programming an application that shows my emulator running, but currently the emulator is only opening Command Prompt windows as if it were ( Start program.bat )

Can anyone help me in C#?

I want to place each .bat window in its location
ex: WebServer.bat, AuthServer.bat, GameServer.bat

[ServerMonitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFnYg.png)